# Deployment-specific configuration for Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script project, for which I have 2 deployments:

- HEAD (development)
- VERSION X (production)

I need to configure these 2 deployments differently (eg different filenames, usernames,...).

What is the best way of doing this? On the Project page of the G Suite Developer Hub I cannot find anything related to "deployment-specific configuration variables".

I read somewhere that you can (should?) use a PropertiesService for this, but again I cannot figure out how to (non-programmatically) edit the values *for a specific deployment*.

Appreciate your suggestions

Comment: What are you publishing, a web application, a G Suite Editor add-on, a G Suite add-on?